# socket is not listening for multiple request

Tags: python, sockets, networking, broadcast

Here is the code for server -

```
import socket, select,re


def getSocket( idd):
  return CONNECTION_LIST[idd]


def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)


def single_client (sock , message , idd):
  socket = getSocket ( idd )
  if socket :
    socket.send(message)
  else:
    print "chudap"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    CONNECTION_LIST = []
    RECV_BUFFER = 4096
    PORT = 5000
    PORTC = 2225

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    listen = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    listen.bind(("0.0.0.0" , PORTC))
    #listen.listen(10)

    CONNECTION_LIST.append(server_socket)
    CONNECTION_LIST.append(listen)
    print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

    idd = 1
    while 1:
        # Get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets = select.select(CONNECTION_LIST,[],[])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            if sock == server_socket:
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd)
                #name = sockfd.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                print "connected from ip %s, id assigned is %d" % (addr[0] , idd)
                broadcast_data(sockfd, "client with IP %s has entered with id = %d\n" % (addr[0] , idd))
                idd += 1
            elif sock == listen:
                print "debugging"
                data,addr = listen.recvfrom(RECV_BUFFER)
                print "Received server probe request from [%s:%s]"%addr
                listen.sendto("iam" , addr)#(addr[0] , 2624))
                listen.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(listen)
                listen = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                listen.bind(("0.0.0.0" , PORTC))
                CONNECTION_LIST.append(listen)
            else:
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if re.findall(r'.*/msg\d+' , data):
                      #print "got single client message request" + data

                      name = "private message from " + re.findall('([^:]+): /msg(\d+)([^"]+)'  , data)[0][0] + ": "
                      #print name

                      eid = int(re.findall('([^:]+): /msg(\d+)([^"]+)'  , data)[0][1])
                      #print eid

                      data = re.findall('([^:]+): /msg(\d+)([^"]+)'  , data)[0][2]
                      #print data

                      data = name + data

                      #print "single client message sent with id = %d" %eid

                      single_client( sock , data , int(eid))
                    elif data:
                        broadcast_data(sock, data)

                except:
                    broadcast_data(sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr)
                    print "Client (%s, %s) is offline" % addr
                    sock.close()
                    CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()
```

Here is the code for client -

```
import socket, select, string, sys

def prompt() :
    sys.stdout.write('<You>: ')
    sys.stdout.flush()

def exit(sock):
  print "\n Thank you for using chat application\nBye"
  sock.close()
  sys.exit()

def printUsage():
  print "1. By default your message will be sent to all clients sitting on the chat server"
  print "2. You can send a private message to a person by starting your message as \"/msg{id}{Your message}\" for example /msg2Hi will send \"hi\" to client with id 2"
  print "3. For quitting simply type \"/q\" or \"/quit\""
  prompt()

PORTS = 2225
PORTC = 2624


if __name__ == "__main__":


    broad = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    broad.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    broad.bind(( '0.0.0.0' , 2624) )
    broad.sendto(b'whoisserver', 0, ("255.255.255.255", PORTS))
    broad.settimeout(10)
    print 15*"-" + "WELCOME TO CHATVILLE" + 15*"-" + "\nFinding the server"
    try:
      data , addr = broad.recvfrom(10)
    except:
      print "Can't find server ! Please ensure that server is up"
      broad.close()
      sys.exit()
    broad.close()


    if data <> "iam":
      print "Can't find a valid server !"
      sys.exit()
    host = addr[0]
    port = 5000
    print addr


#    host = sys.argv[1]
#    port = int(sys.argv[2])
#    print host,port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    name = raw_input("Please Enter your name: ")
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.send(name)
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host. Enjoy...............................'
    name = "<" + name + ">" + ": "
    print " - type /h to see usage instructions any time :) - "
    prompt()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in read_sockets:
            if sock == s:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    print ""
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    prompt()

            else :
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                if str.startswith(msg, "/h") or str.startswith(msg,"/help"):
                  printUsage()
                elif str.startswith(msg, "/quit") or str.startswith(msg,"/q"):
                  exit(s)
                else:
                  msg = name + msg
                  s.send(msg)
                  prompt()
```

Main problem is that only one client is able to connect as soon as the first client connects are to server no other client is able to discover the server.

I tried by looking at the client's code by **tcpdump** and I can see the packet going at port number 2225, but the socket **listen** is not responding at all after the first connection.

PS - earlier I was not making instance of **listen** socket again and again but I tried this also and it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sever `broadcast_data()` does not exclude the UDP socket (`listen`) from the sockets to write to, and so it calls `send()` on that socket. This fails with exception

```
socket.error: [Errno 89] Destination address required
```

because no address is supplied (and can't be with `socket.send()`). The exception handler then closes the UDP socket and no further messages from new clients can be received. That's why additional clients can not connect to the server.

This is a perfect example of why it is not a good idea to use a bare except, i.e. an except statement that handles all exceptions. In this case the handler closes the UDP socket without even logging the fact. There are other instances of bare except statements in your code. I suggest that you handle specific exceptions to avoid this sort of bug. You can fix it by adding the UDP socket to the list of sockets to ignore:

```
def broadcast_data(sock, message):
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket not in (server_socket, sock, listen):
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except socket.error as exc:
                print '!!! An error occurred while writing to client. !!!'
                print exc
                socket.close()
                CONNECTION_LIST.remove(socket)
```

Now no attempt will be made to send messages to the UDP `listen` socket, and the socket won't be closed due to error.

P.S. the code in your main loop that closes and reopens the `listen` socket is not necessary.

Comment: Wow ! literally wow , my mind never thought that this problem can occur here. Thanks :)